# printing the largest value in array

Tags: arrays, c

I was having a trouble regarding to printing out the largest number in array in c language and i don't know how to do it while using loop. Please help me thanks

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {

    int Lnum, size;

    printf("Enter the size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int nums[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\nReversed = ");
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (nums[a] > nums[i]) {
                Lnum = nums[a];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nLargest element = %d", Lnum);
}
```

Comment: replace your last double loop with `Lnum = nums[0]; for (int i=1; i<size; i++) if (nums[i] > Lnum) Lnum  = nums[i];`

Comment: You don't need an array to get the largest number. Nor do you need several loops. A single loop to read a single input, and compare that with the current largest number is enough.

Comment: but we need to use array because it is what we tasked by our prof, thankss though

Comment: Okay, keep the array (for printing out in reverse order) but you can still find out the largest number in the same loop as you use to read input.

Comment: appreciated it mate

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for determining the largest element in an array goes as follows.

1. Use the value of the first array element as a start value for the biggest number.
2. Go over the rest of the array and check for each element if it is a bigger number.
3. When a bigger number is found use the bigger number for further comparisons.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  
  int Lnum, size;
    
    printf("Enter the size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
  
    int nums[size];
  
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\nReversed = ");
    for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--){
      printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
    
    Lnum = nums[0]; // Assume first element to be the largest element
    for(int a=1; a<size; a++){ // start loop with second element
      if(Lnum < nums[a]) { // check if current element is larger
        Lnum = nums[a]; // found larger element, it is now the largest element of all inspected element
      }
    }
    printf("\nLargest element = %d", Lnum);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the size: 3
1 2 3

Reversed = 3 2 1 
Largest element = 3

...Program finished with exit code 0
```